# Send Excel or xls file to remote directory using spring integration

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-integration

I have generated an Excel file using Apache POI API and trying to send it to remote directory using Spring Integration, but when I am writing below code giving compile time error because its only support "File" type object Excel type is "HSSFWorkbook".

```java
HSSFWorkbook workbook = gerateExcelFile(data);

excelCollector.add((workbook);
```

and using below code for "inbound-channel-adaptor"

```xml
<inbound-channel-adapter id="excelAdapter" auto-startup="true"
                 ref="excelCollector" method="poll" channel="excelInputChannel">
    <poller fixed-rate="500"/>
</inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The framework does not know how to process arbitrary objects.

You either need to write the workbook to a `File` or convert it to a byte[] containing the workbook contents, and send that.

Comment: thanks Gary for your reply.  could you suggest me that how I can  write "HSSWorkbook" type  to a File type?

Comment: It's been many years since I used POI; you need to look at their documentation.